# Localhost internal-page links not working (razor html page)

Tags: html, razor, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, blazor

[accordion on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdPIG.png)

What I am trying to do is run an accordion in a Blazor razor html page in a project that I am running locally. Here is the code for that accordion (Bootstrap css), which works perfectly well in an online editor:

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">

            <h5 class="panel-title stath5" id="farmh5">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><span class="badge badge-secondary">4.</span> Farm</a>
                </h5>

            </div>

            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="list-group">

            <li class="list-group-item">
                <p class="statp"><span class="badge badge-info">Quantity of:</span></p>
            </li>
                    
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <label class="statlabel" for="beefCattle"> Beef Cattle:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="beefCattle" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.BeefCattle" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Beef cattle..." autofocus />
            </li>

    
           

        
            <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="dairyCattle"> Dairy Cattle:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="dairyCattle" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.DairyCattle" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Dairy cattle..." />
            </li>

     

    
        

                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="horses"> Horses:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="horses" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Horses" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Horses..." />
                </li>

    
        

                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="hogs"> Hogs:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="hogs" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Hogs" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Hogs..." />
                </li>

    
            
                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="sheep"> Sheep:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="sheep" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Sheep" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Sheep... " />
                </li>
            
        
            <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p class="statp" id="perBunch">Number of birds <b>per bunch:</b></p>
            </li>

            
                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="hens"> Hens:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="hens"  class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Hens" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Hens per bunch..." autofocus />
                </li>

    
         
            <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="breeders"> Breeders:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="breeders" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Breeders" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Breeders per bunch..." />
                </li>

    
            

                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="pullets"> Pullets:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="pullets" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Pullets" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Pullets per bunch..." />
                </li>
            
    
            
        
                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="statlabel" for="broilers"> Broilers:</label><br />
                        <InputNumber id="broilers" class="input" @bind-Value="@Data.FarmData.Broilers" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Broilers per bunch..." />
            </li>
        </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HOWEVER, when I run the blazor page on localhost and click the accordion link, the path `https://localhost:44301/#collapse1` shows up and the accordion does not open. Is this fixed when the accordion is opened from a real website rather than localhost? How so? How can I see it from localhost and resolve this issue?
Any assistance would be invaluable

Comment: Any hints from the browser console?

Comment: How do you mean - I'm not seeing anything special

Comment: F12 to access developer tools, or Command+Option+C on Mac. Click on the console tab.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see anything suggestive there

Comment: You can also try running it in codepen and if it works there, compare the generated CSS with the generated CSS on your site and see if they differ for some reason.

Comment: If there's any other way to resolve it I would appreciate that

Comment: It would be a nightmare to move all of the code and imports to CodePen

Answer (score 0):

```
`https://localhost:44301/#collapse1` is this correct address?
```

There is no file name between slash and anchor - dead end

---

I can be wrong, I don't use localhost, can't check it. It was my first impression, but if machine knows exactly where is it, it can handle this. And without an anchor opens a file? Can you create structure of directories and files different types for test?

Comment: How would I go about adding the filename, it's in localhost

Answer (score 0):

Blazor intercepts nav links, but not if you specify a target

`<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" target="_top">`

Also, bear in mind that if this is not on the "/" route in your app, that you need the route in the href.
For example on a route of "/mypage" your links need to look like this

`<a data-toggle="collapse" href="mypage#collapse1" target="_top">`

Comment: _Thank you_, finally I can get on the project!

Comment: Ok, thought that would work. Guess I was wrong. When I click the accordion link:
```https://localhost:44301/statistics#collapse1```

And nothing changes. The accordion still will not open on localhost

Comment: Presumably you have some JS code that does the actual collapsing because an href link will not do it alone. Do you see any errors in the Dev tools?

Comment: No, I'm using a Bootstrap 4 (which is tested and works). There is one error in the console, about unhandled circuit

Comment: Any ideas about it?